# Is it possible to identify multiple values in a WHENNOT rule when defining WIT object?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are attempting to expose a new field to only two groups (of many) within a TFS team project. We would like to implement a rule to the WIT object for which multiple values would satisfy the issue.

We have tried nested..

```
<WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="1"/>
<WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="2"/>
```

repeated...

```
<WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="1">
</WHENNOT>
<WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="2">
</WHENNOT>
```

and some guesses to the syntax..

```
<WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="1 or 2"/>
<WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="1 || 2"/>
<WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="1, 2"/>
```

without achieving the intended result.

```
<FIELD name="Original Estimate" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>Initial value for Remaining Work - set once, when work begins</HELPTEXT>
    <WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="24">
        <READONLY />
    </WHENNOT>
    <WHENNOT field="System.State" value="To Do">
        <READONLY />
    </WHENNOT>
    <WHEN field="System.State" value="Done">
        <REQUIRED />
    </WHEN>
</FIELD>
```

We would like to show the field based on whether the WIT is associated with Area ID 1 or 2, but otherwise hide from all of others.

Comment: How many areas do you have? I think you can't combine 2 WHENNOT because they cancel each other. you need to use WHEN - RADONLY with all the areas (unless 1 and 2).

Comment: Thanks Shayki. I wasn't looking at it from that angle, but that will work. Unfortunately, there are many areas that we will need to include in the template.

Comment: A lot of work... update here if it worked :)

Comment: Yes it worked, however I am not able to mark your comment as the solution. It must appear in the answers section for me to denote it as a correct method.

Comment: Great! I added it now as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine 2 `WHENNOT` because they cancel each other.

You need to use `<WHEN field="System.AreaId" value="{id}"> <READONLY> </WHEN>`
with all the areas (unless 1 and 2).